# Issues in Use of performSelectorOnMainThread in every millisecond

Tags: iphone, ipad, audiotoolbox, remoteio

I wanna show the amplitude of real time sound on a UIView by graph.

I set sound sample rate as 1000 in a second.

And, To Update Graph, I did like this. this is called in every millisecond.

```
[Audio performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateGraph) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

and inside of updateGraph is like this.

```
- (void) updateGraph{
    [graphview setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

But it draws graph angularly.

http://achievstar.tistory.com/234 
(I'm new in this site so i couldn't upload pictures)

(I guess) it is because of the "waitUntilDone:NO".

iphone 4S and also iPad2 couldn't catch up the rate of 1000.

I also tried "YES" for "waitUntilDone". It draws rightly,

http://achievstar.tistory.com/234
(see the below figure)

but also, the devices couldn't catch up with the rate of 1000,

so in this way, graphing speed was slow.

is there a way to fix the graph better?

I'm really stock here that i couldn't even find good solution any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Just Got a Answer on my own!

I was getting sound input in every millisecond,

and within' it I also updated graph in every millisecond too.

that means I updated every fixel of 480 in a millisecond.

I thought i should update graph immediately when i get sound input,

to show graph smoothly.

But I was wrong. That was not necessary to update every fixel.

Because It really takes a lot of process.

So I changed the code to update UI not in every millisecond. and it works really well.

Comment: And better answer is, I think, using only OpenGL without anything else classes like 'performSelectorOnMainThread'.

Answer (score 0):

`performSelectorOnMainThread` function is mainly used when you are on the background thread and you want to get back on the main thread or you want to perform a function on main thread.

if you are not using any thread or background thread then there is no need to use the `performSelectorOnMainThread` function. you can directly call that function.

try calling the `updateGraph` by using simple self.

i.e [self updateGraph]; and then see the result..

Comment: Actually the code of performSelectorOnMainThread is in the background thread so i used the performSelectorOnMainThread to update UI

Comment: the function, where performSelectorOnMainThread is in, is 'static OSStatus playbackCallback' function (using "RemoteIO"/AudioUnits framework)